# .NET 6 When using Dapper to call a stored procedure, I receive the error The I/O operation has been aborted

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a .NET 6 Windows Service that runs stored procedures. I am using Dapper 2.0.151, and `System.Data.SqlClient` 4.8.6

Let's say that I have a stored procedure `usp_GetFeed` that returns 70,000 rows.

- If I run the stored procedure from within a SQL Server job, it runs fine and takes about 2 minutes
- If I call the stored procedure from the service, using Dapper, around every 2nd or 3rd time I call it, I get the following error:

> Error during SearchPlugin.PullDataFromFeeds:  Feed usp_GetFeed failed: [115520ms] ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync:
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImplAsync(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Object param) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 647
> at Search.Sync.SearchPlugin.Data.DataLayer.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync(String sql) in C:_git\GlobalClearance\Search.Sync.Service\Search.Sync.SearchPlugin\Data\DataLayer.cs:line 245
> ClientConnectionId:8cefc850-0dbd-4837-bbf5-6ef1e736ba86

Here is the code used to call Dapper

```
public class ExecuteStoredProcedureResult<TOutput> 
{
    public IEnumerable<TOutput> Output { get; set; } = new List<TOutput>();
    public int Duration {get;set;}
}

 public async Task<ExecuteStoredProcedureResult<TOutput>> ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<TOutput>(string sql)
 {
     var result = new ExecuteStoredProcedureResult<TOutput>();
     var sw = new Stopwatch();
     sw.Start();

     try
     {
         result.Output = await _connection.QueryAsync<TOutput>(sql, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: _commandTimeoutInSeconds);
         result.Success = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         result.Errors.Add($"{ex}");
     }

     sw.Stop();
     result.Duration = sw.Elapsed;

     return result;
 }
```

On the chance that it is a timeout, I have set

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.Settings.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

But the same behavior occurs.

Comment: This looks like a driver error.  The following says to install Microsoft.Data.SQLClient whic uses ADO.Net (https://www.learndapper.com/database-providers).  Usually errors like this occur because of version of database and driver.  I would update SQLClient https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/released-security-updates-for-microsoft-data-sqlclient-and/ba-p/4024264  Maybe go back one version with dapper https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/2.0.151#versions-body-tab

Comment: @jdweng - switching to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient did the trick - thanks!

Comment: Ran into similar issues between System.Data.SQLClient and the newer Microsoft.Data.SQLClient before and the difference between them is subtle. May be good to put this in an answer for future readers.